# How do I use Jest to test a React view wired to store?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, jestjs, reactjs-testutils

I have a **React view** that communicates with a **store**. I've successfully tested views and stores separately, but not in combination.

I followed the [structure documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25557322/154065) but received a **TypeError**. It looks like Jest is trying to register the store as a component even if I use `dontMock`.

```
Using Jest CLI v0.2.0
 PASS  __tests__/unit/spec/stores/ViewStore-spec.js (0.248s)
 FAIL  __tests__/unit/spec/components/View-spec.react.js (0.942s)
undefined
● View › it defaults to zero unread
  - TypeError: /Users/matnorri/dev/projects/matnorri/web-client/src/app/scripts/components/View.react.js: /Users/matnorri/dev/projects/matnorri/web-client/src/app/scripts/stores/ViewStore.js: Cannot call method 'register' of undefined
        at /Users/matnorri/dev/projects/matnorri/web-client/src/app/scripts/stores/ViewStore.js:43:31
        at Object.runContentWithLocalBindings (/Users/matnorri/dev/projects/matnorri/web-client/node_modules/jest-cli/src/lib/utils.js:357:17)
        ...
```

I've included what I believe is the relevant code below, but can provide it in its entirety if necessary.

**View Jest Test**

```
jest.dontMock('../../../../src/app/scripts/components/View.react');
jest.dontMock('../../../../src/app/scripts/stores/ViewStore');

describe('View', function() {

  var React;
  var TestUtils;
  var ViewComponent;
  var View;

  beforeEach(function() {
    React = require('react/addons');
    TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;
    ViewComponent =
      // Tried both lines with same effect.
      // require('../../../../src/app/scripts/components/View.react.js');
      require('../../../../src/app/scripts/components/View.react');
    View = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<ViewComponent />);
  });

  it('defaults to zero unread', function() {
    View._toString = jest.genMockFunction();
    View._onChange();
    expect(View.state.unread).toBe(0);
  });
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer to your question**

I ran into this issue too and not mocking object-assign solved the issue for me. Add `jest.dontMock('object-assign');` to your spec file. This will solve the problem.

```
// View Jest test
jest.dontMock('../../../../src/app/scripts/components/View.react');
jest.dontMock('../../../../src/app/scripts/stores/ViewStore');
```

---

**To mock or not to mock**

Some more information about when to "mock or not to mock" can be found on the [Jest documentation website](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/automatic-mocking.html#content).

Jest modifies the default behavior of the "require" method and implements it's own require method. This way they are able to mock every function inside a file. So if you want something to really work (like with a store) you should not mock the file.

In your case you're not mocking the ViewStore so every function on this Store will be called. Because you didn't not mock `object-assign` the object assign function doesn't work. This way the ViewStore isn't created the right way (it returns `undefined`) and the test throws the error `Cannot call method 'register' of undefined` as your `assign` function didn't work, because it was mocked.

Again; If you read through the documentation on the Jest website, you'll find a detailed description about when to "mock or not to mock".

---

**Extra info**

I recommend to add "object-assign" and other commonly used modules (like lodash/underscore) to the `unmockedModulePathPatterns` in your test config. More information about this: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#config-unmockedmodulepathpatterns-array-string

Comment: Thank you for the answer, explanation, and additional links. I appreciate it. This one was driving me crazy!

Comment: I know the feeling, took me some time too, before I found out. Glad I could help.

Comment: @stefan, I'm having the same issue, but adding object-assign to my unmocked path, doesn't seem to do anything.  Suggestions?     ```"unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "./node_modules",
      "object-assign"
    ]```

Comment: As @Stefan said, you can add the following to your package.json:   

`"jest": {
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": ["<rootDir>/node_modules"],
  }`

Now you won't need to specify jest.dontMock(...) for your node modules. For more jest configuration options see: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#config-options