# React.js component instance props not mockable via Jest?

Tags: jasmine, reactjs, jestjs

I'm wondering why my mock doesn't seem to be overriding the onclick method of the Component.  Actually it does, except for when I simulate the click.

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
//tests/app/modules/autocompletesearchinput-test.js
jest.dontMock('../../../app/modules/AutocompleteSearchInput.jsx');

var React, TestUtils, FluxxorTestUtils, FluxConstructor, realFlux, fakeFlux, MyComponent, Component;

describe('Testing Autocomplete Search Input', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
        React = require('react/addons');
        TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;
        FluxxorTestUtils = require('fluxxor-test-utils');
        FluxConstructor = require('../../../app/FluxConstructor.js');
        realFlux = FluxConstructor();
        fakeFlux = FluxxorTestUtils.fakeFlux(realFlux);
        fakeFlux.genMocksForStoresAndActions();
        // now all store and action methods are mocked for testing

        MyComponent = require('../../../app/modules/AutocompleteSearchInput.jsx');
        Component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<MyComponent flux={fakeFlux} />);

    });
    it('when created, component should have AutocompleteSearchInput class', function() {
        var div = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(
            Component, 'AutocompleteSearchInput');
    });
    it('when mounted and clicked, should call searchBtnClick', function() {

        Component.searchBtnClick = jest.genMockFunction();
        TestUtils.Simulate.click(Component.refs.searchButton.getDOMNode());
        Component.searchBtnClick();
        expect(Component.searchBtnClick).toBeCalled();
    });
});
```

For reference, I've been using this: [Test a React Component function with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533036/test-a-react-component-function-with-jest)

Comment: `Component.searchBtnClick();` must not be here, you just add this line to make the test passed right ?

Then, have you write `onClick` (camelCase) in you render method (React will ignore `onclick`)

Comment: @ncuillery, ```searchBtnClick``` is totally there!  Its a property in ```React.createClass({})```.  ```onClick``` is also camel case as tag attribute.  The test passes when I use ```Component.searchBtnClick()``` but when I simulate it.  The original method is executed, not the mock.  I need the mock, because the original function will throw an exception. Hmm.  Thanks.

Comment: This is Jest bug.  https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/207